# Can I customize partition names when using Apache Helix?

Tags: java, helix

While playing with Apache Helix I noticed that it automatically generates partition names in following manner: `ResourceName_0`, `ResourceName_1`, ... `ResourceName_N`. It is a bit awkward to translate this back and forth to some real, existing resource names like queues in message broker.

I'm configuring cluster from Java like this, it is a snippet from [rabbitmq-consumer-groups recipe](https://helix.apache.org/1.0.1-docs/recipes/rabbitmq_consumer_group.html).

```
ZkClient zkclient = new ZkClient(ZOOKEEPER_ADDRESS, ZkClient.DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT, ZkClient.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new ZNRecordSerializer());
ZKHelixAdmin admin = new ZKHelixAdmin(zkclient);

// add cluster
admin.addCluster("ClusterName", true);

// add state model definition
admin.addStateModelDef("ClusterName", DEFAULT_STATE_MODEL, new StateModelDefinition(StateModelConfigGenerator.generateConfigForOnlineOffline()));

int partitions = 3;
admin.addResource("ClusterName", "ResourceName", partitions, DEFAULT_STATE_MODEL, IdealState.RebalanceMode.FULL_AUTO.toString());

int replicas = 1;
admin.rebalance("ClusterName", "ResourceName", replicas);
```

Can it be customized somehow?

Comment: There is no tag `apache-helix`, but I don't have enough reputation to add it :(

Comment: `helix` is the tag for [Apache Helix](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/helix/info).